# Alternative to UPDATE with JOIN and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I know that one can not perform UPDATEs with JOINs and LIMITs in MySQL.

The thing is I don't seem to be able to find an alternative to that, and emulate the LIMIT behavior was the only approach I had to solve my timeout problem...

**The problem I am trying to solve:**

I have a gigantic table (timeseriesprevisions) and I need to perform a maintenance operation that looks like this:

```
UPDATE timeseriesprevisions t1
JOIN datasets d1 ON t1.dataset_SID=d1.SID
JOIN datasets d2 ON d1.execution_SID=d2.execution_SID
SET t1.dataset_SID=d2.SID
WHERE t1.sensor_SID={1} AND d1.app_SID=349 AND d2.app_SID={2};
```

**Explanation:** in the gigantic table timeseriesprevisions (with the only fields `sensor_SID` and `dataset_SID`) for a given `sensor_SID`, replace all `dataset_SID` for another one that we will find through 2 JOINs. {1} and {2} are id's.

This throws a timeout exception before the results are set.

My approach to solve this is usually to keep inserting/updating with LIMIT until "affected rows" was zero. This is why I would be interested in an alternative to the JOIN-LIMIT problem in UPDATES. I am not happy with the alternatives I have found so far, including the use of "IN (SELECT ... " (which would make the query way too slow).

Comment: I get it that joins are correctly using indexes... are they? What kind of table is this timeseriesprevisions ? MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: InnoDB. And yes, joins connecting through the right indexes is not an issue, it is tested to work properly. In fact, in order to expand: a simpler similar join update worked fine after the first timeout (I guess because MySQL cached some results and in the second iteration went faster) so I know the procedure is correct. Plus it was tested through SELECTs.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the update in a transaction? It should be faster, and offload a huge part of the burden to the commit statement. Is there any FK involved when you update?

Comment: I am sorry to say I don't know what _enclosing the update in a transaction_ means... and I have done my research. And yes, there are two FKs involved. In fact the huge table consists of a combination of two FKs exclusively.

Comment: can you add the schema definition for the four tables you use in the query? I'd like to understand what happens when you update the dataset_SID. If it propagates to other tables then the process doesn't stop at that update, but might happen in other CASCADE updates.